# Jetty runs old war altought mvn clean is run

Tags: maven-2, jetty

does someone had an similar issue with maven and jetty, that jetty is run with an old war althought mvn clean is run.

My pom uses failsafe to start jetty with mvn verify.

Comment: More details (like a pom allowing to reproduce) required.

Answer (score 1):

see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Temporary+Directories for where jetty store temp files

=> I suggest you configure maven jetty plugin to use a unique temp directory for your application to avoid any problem. e.g.:

```
<project>
...
<plugins>
...
<plugin>
<groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<tmpDir>target/jetty-tmp/myApp</tmpDir>
...
```

see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin