# Spring MVC 3 : Ambiguous mapping found for a non existing method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this "create" method which maps /lists POST petitions. I made an overloaded method "createEmpty()" in order to try something, but later deleted as it throwed a org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException for ambiguous mapping.

The problem is that after I deleted said method, I still get the exception.

```
@Controller
public class ListsController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/lists", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List create(@RequestBody List list) {
    return list;
}
```

> INFO: Dev App Server is now running
>   may 04, 2014 4:21:34 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
>   WARNING: /: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'listsController' bean method 
>   public tacs.tp.list_sharer.domain.List tacs.tp.list_sharer.web.ListsController.createEmpty()
>   to {[/lists],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'listsController' bean method
>   public tacs.tp.list_sharer.domain.List tacs.tp.list_sharer.web.ListsController.create(tacs.tp.list_sharer.domain.List) mapped.
>   may 04, 2014 4:21:34 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
>   WARNING: /: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'listsController' bean method 
>   public tacs.tp.list_sharer.domain.List tacs.tp.list_sharer.web.ListsController.createEmpty()
>   to {[/lists],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'listsController' bean method
>   public tacs.tp.list_sharer.domain.List tacs.tp.list_sharer.web.ListsController.create(tacs.tp.list_sharer.domain.List) mapped.

It seems that createEmpty() is cached somewhere...

Comment: Is there a `createEmpty` method in your `ListController`?

Comment: of course not. mvn clean install fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try to do:
1. If you are using eclipse - Project -> Clean.
2. If you are using maven try to clean and/or install project before deploying.

I see you are using Jetty, maybe these links will help to solve your problems: 
[Cleaning up Jetty - Removing 'unnecessaries' things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995461/cleaning-up-jetty-removing-unnecessaries-things)
[Jetty runs old war altought mvn clean is run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957906/jetty-runs-old-war-altought-mvn-clean-is-run)

Comment: This is not an answer, more likely a comment. Consider providing some real answer.

Comment: mvn clean and then mvn install fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had same **@RequestMapping** value in two different controllers, i removed from one of them and it started working fine.